# Change value of a string multiple times does affect memory?

Tags: c#

I am using a serial device which send always data.
So each time data is been received I save them into a string.

```
private static string TemporaryData = "";

private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                    object sender,
                    SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    TemporaryData = indata;
}
```

Can this code affect my memory? And leading to memory leak?

Comment: You can't change a string, the code merely changes the string object reference.  The string object previously referenced by TemporaryData is eligible for garbage collection.  The odds it will survive for long are extremely low, there is never a need to worry about generation 0 collections.  You should be **much** more worried about the threading race bug in this code.  If other code needs to reliably see the received data, it invariably does, then you need a thread-safe queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Length property of `System.String` is an `Int32`, the maximum length would be `2,147,483,647` chars (max Int32 size). But note that this is the theoretical limit and the practical limit is nowhere near that. So anything longer than that may throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you my question is should i use StringBuilder? or Char[100]?

Comment: If you have a lot of modification (like using this operator `+,-,= ,...`) on your `string`, yes it is good idea to use `StringBuilder`

Comment: The only modification i have is  =    Example `data = ' ' ;`

Comment: If this modifications occurs many times in a short period of time, yes use `StringBuilder`

Comment: Thank you, doest it use smaller memory ?

Comment: Yes absolutely and it gives you better performance.

Comment: Thank you, last question. I will create StringBuilder once, and each time i get new data i will use `stringBuilder.Clear();` and then `stringBuilder.Append()`??

Comment: Yes you can use `clear` methods